# Add images in web to lead form

Tags: web2lead

I am creating a web to lead form. I have to add images in background. Can we add Images in body background in web-to-lead form?
Please help!

Answer (score 4):

Web-to-Lead form is only part of the HTML that is generated in Salesforce specific to what needs to be captured on the form, based on the selections that you may have made. You then provide this generated HTML to the webmaster which is then incorporated on any external website.

As long as the external website's webmaster/developer can configure the HTML to add any additional attributes, without changing the generated Web-to-Lead HTML form, you can do any sort of customization as required, viz., adding a background image.

Any such customization are not part of Salesforce scope.